# openapi-generator duplicates the endpoint in swagger-ui

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, springdoc-openapi-ui, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

The openapi-generator-maven-plugin (version 6.3.0) is configured as follows in a Spring-Boot 3 application:

```
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${openapi-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openApi.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <apiPackage>com.company.api.v1</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.company.model.v1</modelPackage>
                            <supportingFilesToGenerate>ApiUtil.java</supportingFilesToGenerate>
                            <configOptions>
                                <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                                <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

and in the Swagger/OpenAPI Yaml file is only one endpoint configured:

```
paths:
  /table:
    get:
      summary: get all trains
      operationId: trainsList
      tags:
        - zuege
```

The issue here is in the Swagger-Ui; the endpoint is duplicated:

[image]

When I remove the tag in the yaml then only the first endpoint is visible but actually this is the ugly one with the generated description. When I configure it with `<useTags>true</useTags>` ([cf. config](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/spring/)) the two endpoints are still there but both with name `zuege`.

Any idea how to reduce it to only one endpoint but consider the tag?

When I add a global tag description as follows:

```
tags:
  - name: zuege
    description: "Zuege details"
```

together with `<useTags>true</useTags` it looks as follows:

[image]

So it is still duplicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the opeanapi-generator-maven-plugin 6.3.0 because it converts the tag name from the yaml file, e.g.

```
tags:
  - name: zuege
```

into a slightly deviated annotation tag within the generated code, namely:

```
@Tag(name = "Zuege", description = "Zuege details")
public interface ZuegeApi {

}
```

So when you change the tag within the yaml file into the same style (first character is always in upper case), then the issue is gone:

[image]

Comment: As I have seen this Bug is fixed now by version 6.4.0. Thus you can keep your tags in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Just capitalise first letter of your tag name

From

> ```
> tags:
>  - name: zuege
> ```

To

> ```
> tags:
>   - name: Zuege
> ```